# How to rewrite this query to remove Oracle's (+) with LEFT/RIGHT INNER/OUTER JOIN keywords in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

I have the following original query in Oracle,

```
select ...
FROM nvision_trainees_t nv, plans_t p, lookup_t idp_look
WHERE     nv.ned_id = p.trainee_ned_id(+)
      AND p.idp_type_id = idp_look.id(+)
      AND (   
              (p.id IS NULL AND nv.organizationalstat IN ('EMPLOYEE', 'FELLOW')) 
              OR 
               p.id IS NOT NULL
          );
```

This query was migrated to Postgres where `(+)` does not work. I had to rewrite it accordingly. Since it is on the right side of the equality, it implies `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`. So I rewrote the query as below, but it's wrong. I think the reason is, the last condition became part of the `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` whereas originally it was part of an inner join. **It doesn't give the same results.**

```
select ...
from nvision_trainees_t nv 
right outer join plans_t p on p.trainee_ned_id = nv.ned_id 
right outer join lookup_t idp_look on 
            idp_look.id = p.idp_type_id 
            /* I feel that this is wrong somehow, it became part of the RIGHT OUTER JOIN condition */
            and ((p.id is null and nv.organizationalstat in ('EMPLOYEE', 'FELLOW'))
                or p.id is not null);
```

Any tips on how to correctly rewrite the original query with LEFT/RIGHT INNER/OUTER JOINs?

**UPDATE** After I tried [JasonTrue's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71375137/1005607) of separating the bottom clause as its own WHERE, it worked with the **original** `LEFT JOIN`, not the re-written `RIGHT JOIN`, for some reason. In other words, this worked, does anyone know why? Was I on the wrong track with doing a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` for the right-hand `(+)`?

```
  from nvision_trainees_t nv   
  left outer join plans_t p on p.trainee_ned_id = nv.ned_id 
  left outer join lookup_t idp_look on idp_look.id = p.idp_type_id 
  where((p.id is null and nv.organizationalstat in ('EMPLOYEE', 'FELLOW'))
            or p.id is not null);
```

Comment: Yes, you were on the wrong track. `select ... from a, b where a.id = b.id(+)` means **left** outer join of `a` and `b`. That means rows from `a` that don't find a match in `b` will still be in the output - with `null` for all the column values coming from `b`. This is "as if" one had added more rows to `b` (not to `a`!) which explains the `(+)` notation - why it is appended to column references from `b`, not from `a`.

Comment: The SQL parser doesn't care whether you write `where customer_id = 123` or `where 123 = customer_id`, although I've always found the second version somewhat perverse. Exactly the same thing is happening here - it would have been clearer for humans if it had been written forwards as `where p.trainee_ned_id(+) = nv.ned_id` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Added by OP: The right-hand `(+)` is indeed a `LEFT JOIN`, so that should not have been changed to `RIGHT JOIN`. Instead, the problem is as follows)**

In your Oracle example, your final "AND" clause isn't tied to the JOIN operation. In your Postgres one, you make the final AND clause part of your join condition.

I thin you only want the final clause as part of your query filter, not part of the join criteria. Here's an example:

```sql
select ...
from nvision_trainees_t nv 
LEFT outer join plans_t p on p.trainee_ned_id = nv.ned_id 
LEFT outer join lookup_t idp_look on 
            idp_look.id = p.idp_type_id 
WHERE      ((p.id is null and nv.organizationalstat in ('EMPLOYEE', 'FELLOW'))
                or p.id is not null);
```

I haven't tested this, but in ANSI SQL the WHERE clauses typically come after the joins, so I *think* it's equivalent to your original query.

Comment: Thanks but there's still something wrong with this changed query. It doesn't return entries from `nvision_trainees_t` which **do not** exist in `plans_t`. The original query does, I don't know why.

Comment: Actually, after I applied your separated `where` to the **original** query with the **LEFT** JOINs, it started working! No idea why.

Comment: Thanks again. I actually found that `(+)` on the **right side** is **LEFT JOIN**, and vice-versa. https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6585774577187 That's why the original LEFT was correct, but I had to add your separation of the `WHERE` clause, **that** was the culprit. Thanks again - you might want to edit the answer to add this detail, before I accept it.

Comment: Fair enough. It's been around 10 years since I've used Oracle-style syntax so I don't remember the nuances of it; the one place where I used OracleDB regularly, convention was to put the plus around the equals sign.